# Python Spacy's Lemmatizer: getting all options for lemmas with maximum efficiency

Tags: python, performance, nlp, spacy, lemmatization

When using spacy, the lemma of a token (lemma_) depends on the POS. Therefore, a specific string can have more than one lemmas. For example:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
for tok in nlp(u'He leaves early'):
    if tok.text == 'leaves':
        print (tok, tok.lemma_)
for tok in nlp(u'These are green leaves'):
    if tok.text == 'leaves':
        print (tok, tok.lemma_)
```

Will yield that the lemma for 'leaves' can be either 'leave' or 'leaf', depending on context. I'm interested in:

1) Get all possible lemmas for a specific string, regardless of context. Meaning, applying the Lemmatizer without depending on the POS or exceptions, just get all feasible options.

In addition, but independently, I would also like to apply tokenization and get the "correct" lemma.

2) Running over a large corpus only tokenization and lemmatizer, as efficiently as possible, without damaging the lemmatizer at all. I know that I can drop the 'ner' pipeline for example, and shouldn't drop the 'tagger', but didn't receive a straightforward answer regarding parser etc. From a simulation over a corpus, it seems like results yielded the same, but I thought that the 'parser' or 'sentenzicer' should affect? My current code at the moment is:

```
import multiprocessing
our_num_threads = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
corpus = [u'this is a text', u'this is another text'] ## just an example
nlp = spacy.load('en', disable = ['ner', 'textcat', 'similarity', 'merge_noun_chunks', 'merge_entities', 'tensorizer', 'parser', 'sbd', 'sentencizer'])
nlp.pipe(corpus, n_threads = our_num_threads)
```

If I have a good answer on 1+2, I can then for my needs use for words that were "lemmatized", consider other possible variations.

Thanks!